# Why funcion self.spacy_nlp(phrase) doen't no work

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Forgive me if I say any improper things.
We keep a project developed in python which makes an analysis of the feeling of the customer comments. The steps are simple:

1. Extract source comments and dump them into a .csv
2. Clean comments and dump clean comments on another csv
3. Analyze the comments
4. Up the feeling to the bbd

The problem is at point 3 and we don't understand what's going on. The problem is this,
The clean_data_path variable receives the file with the clean comments:

```
def run(clean_data_path, predictions_data_path):
   
   
    logger.info("Data analysis started!")

    logger.info("Loading clean data...")
    df = pd.read_csv(clean_data_path)

    logger.info("Loading comments to analyze...")
    review_id, _, comments = load(df)

    logger.info("Sentiment analysis...")
    domain_dict = load_domain_dict()
    nlp = NLP(
        domain_dict=domain_dict,
        domain_dict_cap=conf.DOMAIN_DICT_CAP,
        max_review_len=conf.MAX_REVIEW_LEN,
    )
    words =  list(map(nlp.phrase_to_words, comments))

When executing the sentence :
    words = list(map(nlp.phrase_to_words, comments))
```

It just fails to continue and we don't know how to capture the error. We tried to put try i except but it doesn't come out.
If we look at the nlp.phrase_to_words we see the following code:

```
class NLP():
    """
    Class designed to carry out all the actions related with text
    manipulation and basic NLP tasks.
    """
    def __init__(self, domain_dict, domain_dict_cap, max_review_len):
        """
        TODO
        """
        self.domain_dict = domain_dict
        self.domain_dict_cap = domain_dict_cap
        self.max_review_len = max_review_len
        self.spacy_nlp = spacy.load('es_core_news_sm')
   …
   …..
def phrase_to_words(self, phrase):
        """
        Given a phrase as a string, it returns a list with the words
        in that phrase. 
        
        Args
        ---- 
            phrases : Phrase to tokenize

        Returns
        -------
            List with the words of the phrase
        """ 
           print("before")
           doc = self.spacy_nlp(phrase)
           print("after", doc)
           return list(map(str, doc))
```

The problem for that is when you call self.spacy_nlp(phrase). Don't run, simply exit.
But the strangest thing is that if I execute the process putting a complete path of the file clean_data_path it works correctly and is able to execute doc = self.spacy_nlp(phrase) (the same file that it uses when it executes the whole process)

The process worked perfectly until a week ago

Someone could give me some guidance or have found something like this

Greetings,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sounds like a nasty problem. If everything worked before, I certainly would suspect the input data and check whether something has changed in the format or encoding such as newlines and so on. I'm afraid I have no experience with nlp and spacy, but I'm sure there will be others that might be able to help you further.

Comment: Thanks Ronald. The strange is when the file clean_data_path  is created ( for example 2020-07-24_cleaned.csv) and force the program to read this file by  df = pd.read_csv("home/files/2020-07-24_cleaned.csv") run perfectly

Comment: Can you please run `python -m spacy validate` in your development environment to see if the language model is compatible with your current version of `spacy` installation.

Comment: Yes, I did. The result is :     Installed models (spaCy v2.0.16)
    /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy

    TYPE        NAME                  MODEL                 VERSION                                   
    package     es-core-news-sm       es_core_news_sm       2.0.0    ✔      
    link        es_core_news_sm       es_core_news_sm       2.0.0    ✔